# VB.NET - Manually raise FormClosing Event

Tags: vb.net, events, formclosing

Im quiet new to vb.net and I'm trying to create a special system when a user closes a form.
For my system I would like to raise the FormClosing Event manually.

-> So: How can I raise the FormClosing Event from somewhere in the code?

Info: The form is popping up as a "ShowDialog".

Thank You!

Comment: Why not just call `Close` on the form?

Comment: Sure! Was too easy to think off.. May you know the answer to comment nr. 2 in Steve's answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually force the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event you call the [Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) method using the instance of the form to close.

This means that your call to Close() should be done from inside the form shown because you have used `ShowDialog()`. This method is modal and doesn't return the control until the form is closed

The FormClosing event receive a FormClosingEventArgs parameter where you could find the [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx) property. This property is an enum where you could check the reason for the closing event.

If the reason is `UserClosing` then you could set the property Cancel of the FormClosingEventArgs to true (leaving the form open) and call you own procedure

Comment: Thank you very much! Thinking to complicate just prevent me from finding that simple answer.

Comment: May you know how to unbind the standard-FormClosing Event from the X-Button of a Form and bind some custom Event instead?

Comment: Not a direct rebinding, but a workaround could be devised. Check the updated answer